# Devise token auth can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I try to create app in rails, which would be regular web application and also an api for mobile application written in react native. I take advantage of "devise token auth" gem along wiht "devise". 
I added  gems to Gemfile and ran bundle. Next I ran
`rails g devise_token_auth:install User auth`. Finally I changed routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  namespace :api do
    scope :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
    end
  end
end
```

Fortunately regular sign_in and sign_up work for web app, however when I try to send request to api using curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"test123@gmail.com","password":"aaaaaaaa"}' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_in
```

I get message "can't verify CSRF token authenticity"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSRF token authenticity check is originating from your Rails Application Controller.

```
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

There are a variety of ways you can handle the situation, but from the rails guide, they [suggest adding a header](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures):

> By default, Rails includes jQuery and an unobtrusive scripting adapter
>   for jQuery, which adds a header called X-CSRF-Token on every non-GET
>   Ajax call made by jQuery with the security token. Without this header,
>   non-GET Ajax requests won't be accepted by Rails. When using another
>   library to make Ajax calls, it is necessary to add the security token
>   as a default header for Ajax calls in your library. To get the token,
>   have a look at  tag
>   printed by <%= csrf_meta_tags %> in your application view.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually considered a feature of Rails to protect you from CSRF attacks. Devise probably implements some form of forgery protection so you can't make non-GET requests without a proper token (this token is added to requests made from Rails itself but not Curl). You can look at the rails documentation for "protect_from_forgery". I would include a link but I am not sure which version of Rails you are using.